# Problem with dynamic allocation in c++, working only for the very first iterations

Tags: c++

Using N = 60000, R0 = 1.5, l = 1

I've just started to code and I can not find the reason why dynamic allocation used in this piece of code works only for the very first iterations:

```
{
    double *I = new double;
    I[0]= l;
    double *S = new double;
    S[0] = N;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++ ){
        I[i] = I[i-1]*R0;
        S[i] = S[0] - I[i]*R0;
        cout << "I[" << i << "] " << I[i] << ", " << " S[" << i << "] " << S[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

I[1] 1.5,  S[1] 59997.8

I[2] 2.25,  S[2] 59996.6

I[3] 3.375,  S[3] 59994.9

I[4] 5.0625,  S[4] 1.12882e-312

I[5] 7.59375,  S[5] 2.122e-314

I[6] 11.3906,  S[6] 0

I[7] 17.0859,  S[7] -20.5664

I[8] 25.6289,  S[8] -33.3809

I[9] 4.65997e-310,  S[9] 5.0625

I[10] 3.18299e-314,  S[10] 5.0625

I[11] 0,  S[11] 5.0625

I[12] 0,  S[12] 5.0625

I[13] 0,  S[13] 5.0625

I[14] 0,  S[14] 5.0625

First time on stack overflow, thanks for the patience

Comment: Why on earth are you not using a [std::vector<double>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for this?? Stop that manual memory management nonsense - it's not the 1990's and C++98 any more.

Comment: You have done a good post.  Welcome.to stackoverflow.  Keep pushing.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
double *I = new double;
```

allocates only a *single* double. Then indexing into `I` with something like `I[10]` is not allowed (it invokes undefined behavior).

If you need to allocate an array of `double`s, you need to do:

```
double *I = new double[100];
```

You need to do the same thing for `S` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new pointer I and S, which are points on array of 100 values of double.

```
double *I;
I = new double[100];
I[0]= l;
double *S;
S = new double[100];
S[0] = N;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++ ){
    I[i] = I[i-1]*R0;
    S[i] = S[0] - I[i]*R0;
    cout << "I[" << i << "] " << I[i] << ", " << " S[" << i << "] " 
}
```